# How did humans get to the planet?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In Episode 15 of Season 2 of Deep Space Nine, "Paradise", how is it that humans got to the other side of the wormhole? The colonists say they were there for 10 years, and

> The leader said she found the place months before they arrived to
>  setup the duonetic field.

Yet, they are in the Gamma Quadrant. Was it ever explained how they'd traveled so far?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is not on the other side of the worm hole. From [MemoryAlpha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradise_%28Star_Trek%3a_Deep_Space_Nine%29):

> While on a **reconnaissance mission of star systems near the Bajoran wormhole**, O'Brien and Sisko discover human life signs on an uncharted planet. Beaming to the surface, they suddenly discover that a duonetic energy field has disabled all of their electronic devices. They meet Joseph and Vinod, part of a group of colonists who became stranded ten years ago in a similar fashion.

Deep Space 9 is still in deep space as far as the Federation is concerned. Most of that area is unknown to the Federation.

Comment: "Station log, stardate 47573.1. To respond to questions about setting up colonies near the wormhole, Chief O'Brien and I have set out to survey nearby star systems."

Answer (score 3):

It's established in the script that Sisko and O'Brien are exploring systems *close to the wormhole* (e.g. rather than through it).

> **SISKO (V.O.):** *Station log, Stardate 47573.1.  We're getting more and
>   more requests for information about setting up colonies in sectors
>   close to the wormhole. So, Chief O'Brien and I have set out to survey
>   near-by star systems for M-Class planets.*
>
> ...
>
> **SISKO:** *It's M-Class all right.  One hundred and sixty million kilometers from Orellius Minor.  Should be a perfect place to set up a colony...*
>
> <sub><sup>[DS9: Paradise - Original Screenplay](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/435.txt)</sup></sub>

And while it's not made *abundantly* clear in the episode that they're on the Alpha Quadrant side, the additional materials provided (the [Star Trek Star Charts](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Star_Charts) factbook and the [official StarTrek.com Databank](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/orellius-minor)) leave no room for interpretation whatsoever.

[image]

> **Orellius Minor:** *Name for an F-type star in Sector 401 -- adjacent to the Bajoran sector -- and its major, Class M world orbiting at 160 million km. The previously unscouted planet is found to host a human colony, led by an idealistic but single- minded opponent of technology who kept Commander Sisko and Chief O'Brien captive until they escaped in 2370.*
>
> <sub><sup>http://www.startrek.com/database_article/orellius-minor</sup></sub>